# How do you compute this orthogonal projection

Tags: convex-analysis, projection

Suppose that $K \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix and $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ is the positive quadrant in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (including the boundaries). Let $X = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: Kx \in \mathbb{R}^n_+\}.$

Compute the orthogonal projection of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ onto $X$, this is,
$$\mathrm{proj}_X(x) := \mathrm{arg\ min}\{\frac{1}{2}\Vert u - x\Vert^2: u\in X\}.$$